# Regex javascript exclude one character

Tags: json, regex, notepad++

I need to find this string:

```
{ "any string but :",
```

for example:

```
{ id,
{ this.content,
{ var = {123},
```

I'm searching it on Notepad++ with:

```
{ (.*?),
```

But I don't know how to exclude the : with

```
^\:\
```

Any help? thanks.

Undesire results:

```
{ id:id,
```

I'm searching for a javascript syntax error. By mistake, someone has defined JSONS as:

```
{ id, data, etc, etc,...}
```

When they have to be (this is the correct way):

```
{ id: id, data: something, etc:etc, etc:something,...}
```

So I want to find where that string doesn't have the : (which is correct)

Comment: It's unclear for me. You should also show undesired cases.

Comment: Ok, edited with undesired results.

Comment: Do you want to do a search and replace?

Comment: No, just a search, I needed to find a string like "{ id, " only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
{[^:]*?,
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxkgVr/1)**

Update: I noticed you updated your question. So, for your edited question you can use:

```
{[^:]*?,|(?<=, )\w+,
```

**[Working demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lxkgVr/2)**

Comment: This regex does not find that string in question. OP writes *I need to find this string*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP says _any string but :_ meaning that he wants everything that doesn't have colons. Probably he wants invalid json

Comment: Works fine, how would be without enters? I'm just searching for a invalid JSON syntax, for example:  { id, data}

Comment: @pmirnd can you update the link I gave you with the other samples?

Comment: I edited my question with more information about what I need.

Comment: It fails on `{ id, var = {123}, etc, etc,...}`

Comment: @revo let me check

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lxkgVr/3 I have to keep out the newlines, that regex show those results too

Comment: @pmirnd add the `\n` to the class, you can use this `{[^:\n]*?,|(?<=, )\w+,`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did too.